# Duplicate key error after MariaDB replication setup

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication

Looking for guidance as to what I continue to do wrong when trying to perform a basic replication setup between a single primary and replication servers.

Through several trials over the years, this has been inconsistent at best.  My more recent attempt (steps) are shown below, which is a culmination from several sites, including the MariaDB support site.

**Goal:**  Use mariabackup or other recommended method to backup the database from the primary server, restore to the replication server and successfully replicate data from the primary to the replication server.

Using Mariabackup to capture a backup of the data

**On the master server**

Run the following command at MySQL command prompt

```
flush privileges; flush tables with read lock;
```

**WHILE THE DB IS LOCKED**

**Run this command to backup**

```
mariabackup --defaults-file="m:\mariadb\my.ini" --backup --target-dir="m:\backup" --user user --password pass
```

**After the backup, run the command to prepare**

```
mariabackup --defaults-file="m:\mariadb\my.ini" --prepare --target-dir="m:\backup" --user user --password pass
```

**NOTE**
Once prepare is complete, make sure to run 'unlock tables' in the MariaDB command prompt window.

The prepare command will show the binlog file and position to use in CHANGE MASTER TO, so be sure to capture the output from the prepare command after it completes.

**Example output from prepare command**

```
mariabackup based on MariaDB server 10.3.12-MariaDB Win64 (AMD64)
mariabackup: cd to m:\backup\
mariabackup: This target seems to be not prepared yet.
mariabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration for recovery:
mariabackup:   innodb_data_home_dir = .
mariabackup:   innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
mariabackup:   innodb_log_group_home_dir = .
mariabackup: Starting InnoDB instance for recovery.
mariabackup: Using 104857600 bytes for buffer pool (set by --use-memory paramete
r)
2020-11-02 22:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocke
d functions
2020-11-02 22:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-11-02 22:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-11-02 22:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-11-02 22:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-11-02 22:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 100M
, instances = 1, chunk size = 100M
2020-11-02 22:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-11-02 22:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN
=936805148847
2020-11-02 22:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Last binlog file '.\master-bin.000003', pos
ition 167707395
Last binlog file .\master-bin.000003, position 167707395
201102 22:46:50 completed OK!
```

**RESTORING THE DB**
Copy the backup directory from the master over to the root of the DB drive on the slave

Log in to the slave server and open a command prompt to the backup directory

Run the command to copy restore the backup to the slave data directory

```
mariabackup --copy-back --target-dir="M:\backup" --datadir="m:\mariadb\data" --user infinity --password infinitydb
```

Start the MariaDB service on the slave server

Run the following change master to command with appropriate values

**Example**

```
CHANGE MASTER TO master_host="idk3-vm5", master_log_file='master-bin.000003', master_log_pos=167707395, master_port=3306, master_user="repl", master_password="repl", master_use_gtid=current_pos;
```

**Start and check slave**

```
start slave; 

show slave status \G
```

**Error upon starting replication**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: Queueing master event to the relay log
                   Master_Host: idk3-vm5
                   Master_User: repl
                   Master_Port: 3306
                 Connect_Retry: 60
               Master_Log_File: master-bin.000002
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 604529766
                Relay_Log_File: idk3-vm8-relay-bin.000002
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 1631
         Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000002
              Slave_IO_Running: Yes
             Slave_SQL_Running: No
               Replicate_Do_DB:
           Replicate_Ignore_DB:
            Replicate_Do_Table:
        Replicate_Ignore_Table:
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:    Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                    Last_Errno: 1062
                    Last_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'idk3-vm8-OrderInjector' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'idf'. Query: 'INSERT INTO `idf`. `idf_client_version` (`idf`.`idf_client_version`.`HOSTNAME`,`idf`.`idf_client_ve rsion`.`SOFTWARE`,`idf`.`idf_client_version`.`VERSION`,`idf`.`idf_client_version `.`LAST_CONNECTED`) VALUES ('idk3-vm8','OrderInjector','20.2.11','2020-11-02 11: 29:13')'
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1331
               Relay_Log_Space: 604530378
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File:
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File:
            Master_SSL_CA_Path:
               Master_SSL_Cert:
             Master_SSL_Cipher:
                Master_SSL_Key:
         Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL  Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 0
                 Last_IO_Error:
                Last_SQL_Errno: 1062
                Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'idk3-vm8-OrderInjector' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'idf'. Query: 'INSERT INTO `idf`. `idf_client_version` (`idf`.`idf_client_version`.`HOSTNAME`,`idf`.`idf_client_ve rsion`.`SOFTWARE`,`idf`.`idf_client_version`.`VERSION`,`idf`.`idf_client_version `.`LAST_CONNECTED`) VALUES ('idk3-vm8','OrderInjector','20.2.11','2020-11-02 11: 29:13')'    Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
              Master_Server_Id: 1
                Master_SSL_Crl:
            Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                    Using_Gtid: Slave_Pos
                   Gtid_IO_Pos: 0-1-701693
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:    Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                 Parallel_Mode: conservative
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State:
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0 Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 3 1 row in set (0.003 sec)
```

Given that I have flushed privileges, flushed tables, and locked the DB and THEN captures the backup, I do not understand why I continue to get duplicate key after restoring and completing the replication configuration.

If someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: on slave status, binary logs are reading from file master-bin.000002 while backup have been taken till  master_log_file='master-bin.000003', master_log_pos=167707395.

Please run commands on slave server `reset slave all;` and again change master

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have ran stop slave, reset slave, reset slave all, a number of times and repeated the change master to.  I have even done these things, went back to the master, flushed priv, locked tables, captured a new log and pos via show master status and used this in my change master to command and every time, I get the duplicate key errors when starting replication.

Comment: Check that `idf`.`idf_client_version` is declared the same on both servers. (SHOW CREATE TABLE `idf`.`idf_client_version`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on slave status, binary logs are reading from file **`master-bin.000002`** while backup have been taken till `master_log_file='master-bin.000003', master_log_pos=167707395.` Please run commands on slave server

> reset slave all;
>
> CHANGE MASTER TO master_host="idk3-vm5",
> master_log_file='master-bin.000003', master_log_pos=167707395,
> master_port=3306, master_user="repl", master_password="repl";
>
> start slave;

NOTE: `master_use_gtid=current_pos;` is not required here. Once slave will be insync then You can change with GTID.

Comment: This worked perfectly and things are now in sync - much appreciated.  So once things are in sync, it is then good to run CHANGE MASTER TO master_use_gtid=current_pos, correct?  This is listed as a recommended thing to do on the MariaDB replication support site.

Comment: if slave in sync. First check gtid if slave_pos and current_pos are same or not.